# Adding rows for missing year by group

Tags: r, dataframe

In an R data.frame I would to find the missing year by group and add a row for
each missing year and repeat the last value.

An example

This is a `data.frame`

```
 1. GROUP/YEAR1/YEAR2/YEAR3
 2. A/100/190/na
 3. A/90/na/300
 4. B/200/70/na
```

I Want

```
1. GROUP/YEAR1/YEAR2/YEAR3
  2. A/100/190/190
  3. A/90/90/300
  4. B/200/70/70
```

Comment: Here is [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `complete` from `tidyr` to complete the sequence, and then `fill` to fill the NAs per group, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 complete(YEAR, GROUP) %>% 
 group_by(GROUP) %>% 
 fill(VALUE)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
> # Groups:   GROUP [2]
>    YEAR  GROUP VALUE
>   <int> <fctr> <int>
> 1  2000      A   190
> 2  2001      A   200
> 3  2000      B    70
> 4  2001      B    70
> ```

**EDIT**

As per your new requirements, it seems as though you only need to fill NAs rowwise. In that case, a simple base R solution could be,

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(i) zoo::na.locf(i))))
```

Comment: don't put it here. Edit it in your question

Comment: Hi Sotos, excuse me but I change my question. I don't know how write to you directly. I'm a beginner. For the moment thank you very veru much. If you can reply to my new post it will very helpfull.

Comment: Updated my answer. Have alook

Comment: Regarding the EDIT you want the `apply` to only work on the numeric columns so I think you want this: `library(zoo); replace(df, -1, apply(df[-1], 1, na.locf0))` .

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use `merge` with `expand.grid` to pad missing rows and `na.locf` to fill NA.

```r
df <- merge(expand.grid(GROUP=unique(df$GROUP), YEAR=unique(df$YEAR)), df, all=T)
library(zoo)
df$VALUE <- zoo::na.locf(df$VALUE)
df
```

Output is:

```
  GROUP YEAR VALUE
1     A 2000   190
2     A 2001   200
3     B 2000    70
4     B 2001    70
```

Comment: @diego the updated dataset and expected output seems to have a typo - header has 4 columns but data has 5 columns. You may need to update the sample & expected dataset properly.